# How do we call a website that perform things without doing in requests?

Tags: web-application

How we call a website that perform things like translating or anything else, without performing an action/request or JavaScript event ?

Take for example [this](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/atbash.php) site, the cipher text is generated without making any requests (You can see it in the network tab in dev tools). How do we call this type of site ?

Comment: It's a static HTML page, containing a JavaScript application that runs completely on the client side (the JavaScript code runs in the browser and does not interact with the server in any way). I don't know if there is a specific name for this architecture. Anyway, this question has nothing to do with security, so it is going to be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser makes at GET request for that page, which loads a combination of HTML and JavaScript.  The JavaScript function start_update is called nearly immediately:

```
window.setTimeout('start_update()', 100);
```

start_update in turn calls upd():

```
upd();
```

And upd() applies encryption if there is new text, doesn't if there isn't, and calls itself either way:

```
window.setTimeout('upd()', 100);
```

So upd() is effectively a busy loop that will call itself every 100 milliseconds, allowing the page to update itself "magically", all through the JavaScript running in your browser.

This isn't really AJAX because the JavaScript isn't making XMLHttpRequest calls and isn't getting text, JSON, or XML from any other source.  It's simply an HTML page with embedded JavaScript which runs in a busy loop rather than being event-driven.

Comment: Thanks, one more question. what does the web-application need to change in order to make a request to this JavaScript function ? And how does it work ?

Comment: @AskingQuestions Every time upd() runs, it's checking for changes to document.encoder.text, which corresponds to `form name="encoder"` and `textarea name="text"` in the HTML.  But it's a loop checking, not an event driving the upd() function.  "how does it work" is too vague for me to be sure what you're asking about.

Comment: I still don't understand why there is no request, can I guess ? Maybe because that the web-application is not communicate with the web-server ?

Comment: @AskingQuestions There is no request because the JavaScript (loaded and running in the browser) is interacting with the HTML (in the browser) and what the user types (in the browser).  The actions of the page are completely contained within the browser, and do not need to talk to the server for any reason.